# Is it possible to add new runlevel in initd or systemd?

Tags: systemd, init, runlevel

Can I add a new runlevel to initd/systemd?

> ## These are the default runlevels in Slackware:
>
> ## 0 = halt
>
> ## 1 = single user mode
>
> ## 2 = unused (but configured the same as runlevel 3)
>
> ## 3 = multiuser mode (default Slackware runlevel)
>
> ## 4 = X11 with KDM/GDM/XDM (session managers)
>
> ## 5 = unused (but configured the same as runlevel 3)
>
> ## 6 = reboot

can I customize initd/systemd to reconize a new runlevel like this:

> ## These are the default runlevels in Slackware:
>
> ## 0 = halt
>
> ## 1 = single user mode
>
> ## 2 = unused (but configured the same as runlevel 3)
>
> ## 3 = multiuser mode (default Slackware runlevel)
>
> ## 4 = X11 with KDM/GDM/XDM (session managers)
>
> ## 5 = unused (but configured the same as runlevel 3)
>
> ## 6 = reboot
>
> ## 7 = myrunlvl

and change the initd to know this cmd

> init 7
> then run my "myrunlvl"

Comment: Systemd doesn't use runlevels at all, so it seems a bit of a skew question.

Comment: Are you running slackware? In that case rather go to [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com). If not you have `systemd` and could well define new targets over new runlevels.

Comment: what you are looking for is  a "target" and yes, you can create those. the old "runlevels" in systemd are symlinks to a target.

Comment: my question is to make that target as an init cmd like init 1 .. without using systemctl isolate myrunlevel8.target instead init 8 then start "mytarget" the question is : is it possible to customize the init cmds? thanks for advance